# How can run "gradle -q dependencies" in ubuntu by Android Studio? (zsh: command not found: gradle)

Tags: android, ubuntu, gradle, environment

I have gradle-android project, and I want run command in terminal, I go to my-project and run: "`gradle -q dependencies`", But I have: `zsh: command not found: gradle`, I added GRADLE_HOME/bin to my PATH environment variable.

```
GRADLE_HOME="/home/myName/gradleParams/gradle-2.2.1/bin"

echo $GRADLE_HOME
/home/myName/gradleParams/gradle-2.2.1/bin
```

But I have `zsh: command not found: gradle` so far :( Why?

Comment: Try `echo $PATH`. Perhaps you have not reloaded that terminal to pick up the new `PATH`. Also, `GRADLE_HOME` is usually set to `/home/myName/gradleParams/gradle-2.2.1`, not the `bin/` subdirectory, where you add the `bin/` as you put this into the `PATH`.

Comment: As CommonsWare says: `GRADLE_HOME` has no special meaning to your shell while `PATH` tells it where to look for commands/executables.